# gdaladdo adding stripes to data

Tags: gdal, gdaladdo

I created some image overviews for a large (1.2 Gb) topo relief image.

```
gdaladdo -r cubic -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES relevo_srtm_br_30m.tif 2 4 8 16 32
```

But as a result I'm getting some stripes on my overviews
[image: Overview with stripes]

However, when I zoom in enough to look at the original data, the stripes disappear.
[image: No stripes at high zoom levels]

Is this beeing caused by the cubic interpolation?

Comment: Because you are creating external overviews it is very easy to test. Rename you cubic overview file from .ovr into .bak_cubic and create new version of overviews with different settings. That is one big advantage in using external overviews at least during the development period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did what user30184 suggested. And yes, it looks like the stripes are caused by cubic interpolation. Using the average resampling things look a lot better.[image: Brasil relief - average resampling interpolator - no stripes]

But I still get a bit of stripes at some zoom levels. Not as strong as the ones obtained with cubic.[image]